# I want to print the value between 2 to 5 from 1first columns

Tags: python

I want to print the value between 2 to 5 from 1first columns.

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': ['C4GSP3JOIHJ2', 'CAGPS3JOIHJ2','CALCG3EST2','CLCCV3JOIHJ2','CLCNF3JOIHJ2','CLCQU3JOIHJ2','CLSMS3JOIHJ2','CMICO3JOIHJ2'],
    })
```

**output look like this**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by value between 2 to 5?

Comment: df['output']=df['colA'].apply(x:x[1:6])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`df5['output']=df5['colA'].str[1:6]`

Answer (score -1):

```
df['output'] = df.colA.apply(lambda x: x[1:6])
```

should work. Docs for apply function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html